# Firebase Analytics not available

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

I can't use Firebase with iOS. I'm using Xcode 8.0 and Objective-C. I added all the necessary framework and the right code to my `AppDelegate` implementation.

I added the ObjC to Other Linker Flags and I added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` but the App crashes with this error:

[image: Error]

Comment: I also got this warning.I forgot to include 'Firebase/core' in pod file.After adding this in pod file & updating pod..issue resolved.

Answer (score 8):

"FIRAnalytics is not available" is exactly the error that will occur when directly integrating the Firebase frameworks without using CocoaPods and not setting the -ObjC Linker flag. Make sure you set it properly:

Add the -ObjC linker flag in **Other Linker Settings** in your target's build settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I had setting correctly the "Other Linker Flag" has you suggested. The problem was that I had the GoogleSignIn.framework already in my project and it created a conflict with the GoogleUtilities.framwork installed with Firebase. Removing the GoogleSignIn.framework solved the problem.

Comment: I also have this bug, how ever -Objc is set? I am trying to use Firebase in a framework, I think the issue has something to do with the way xcode handles dependencies in frameworks

Comment: I am using objective - C and still getting this issue ? Do you know how to resolve it ?

Comment: @AshutoshShukla The option is -ObjC