# [Firebase/Core][I-COR000022] Firebase Analytics is not available

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

[Firebase/Core][I-COR000022] Firebase Analytics is not available.

Why is this happening?

What I did.....
I did a manually install of the Firebase SDK to my iOS project

I added -ObjC  in Other link flag

Is there anything more to do?

Answer (score 4):

This occur when firebase framework is integrated without using CocoaPods. Make sure you set the -ObjC linker flag properly.

You can also check [Firebase Analytics not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617804/firebase-analytics-not-available?rq=1)