# 5.4.1 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000022] Firebase Analytics is not available

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I manually installed Firebase Crashlytics into my ios project a few days ago.
It worked fine.Some crash reports showed up in console.
Now i want to log some events, and i get "Firebase Analytics is not available".
Is there anything else to do?
[other linker flags image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvlal.png)

Comment: Did you see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617804/firebase-analytics-not-available)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Analytics not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617804/firebase-analytics-not-available)

Comment: already add -ObjC. Still not works.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when you've installed the `FirebaseCore` pod, but have not installed `FirebaseAnalytics`. See [source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Core/FIRApp.m#L334).

If you don't want Analytics, you can safely ignore the message. If you do want Analytics, add the FirebaseAnalytics framework to your app.

Using CocoaPods, the Analytics installation happens automatically when you include the Firebase/Core subspec in the Podfile with `pod 'Firebase/Core'`.